# example of positive but not completely positive operator

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras

I was looking for some example of a positive operator which is not completely positive on a banach algebra. if I consider my banach algebra to be $\text{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ of matrices over complex numbers. And consider my operator as $A$ going to transpose of $A$. So this operator is coming out to be positive. Is this map completely positive as well or its just positive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transpose is the obvious example. That it is not completely positive,  can be quickly checked by using [Choi–Jamiołkowski isomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel-state_duality).

Following [Woronowicz](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0034-4877%2876%2990038-0) (who used techniques of [St{\o}rmer](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02391860)) you can show that any positive map $\phi:M_2(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow M_2(\mathbb{C})$ can be decomposed as a completely positive $+$ transpose of a completely positive map.

If you consider $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ for $n\geq3$, then there are a few examples which can not be written in the above form. The first and the most famous example was constructed by [Choi](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379575900580). For a quick review and a list of such maps, see the paper by [Chruscinski and  Kossakowski](http://in.arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0606211).

The problem is more complicated if you consider sub-algebras of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C}^n)$ or when the $C^*$ algebra is infinite dimensional.

Answer (score 4):

Transposition is not completely positive. For the proof see example 3.6 page 24 of [this notes](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pskoufra/OANotes-CompletelyPositiveMaps.pdf).